# Explanations about a proof that if a series converges absolutely, then any rearrangement of the series has the same limit

Tags: real-analysis

I find the proof in the blue box in the slides problematic.

Here, $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection.
[image]

In the proof, we are supposed to consider $\forall m\geq M$.

But it is considering the terms $b_{n}$ with $n\leq M$ & $n\neq \{f(k): 1\leq k \leq N\}$

and forgetting the terms $b_{m}$ with $m> M$

\

Or did i misunderstood the proof?

Comment: Can you point out the lines  with which you are having a problem? Mention which slide it is (top left, top right, bottom left), and which line it is, because I think you have misunderstood the proof.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг edited

Comment: I agree, it's a bit convoluted. I'll try and demystify it.

Comment: I find problematic to assume from the start that if one does not understand a proof then it must be "flawed". Reformulated the title to avoid this turn of phrase.

Comment: @Did Which part of the proof did i understand incorrectly? I thought i have understood it correctly.

Comment: What? Are you not asking for "explanations about a proof that if a series converges absolutely, then any rearrangement of the series has the same limit"?

Comment: @Did Yes, because i feel the proof is incomplete. Look at my original post. If u feel im not thinking right, pls tell me. I would like to solve my misunderstandings. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, so the new title is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a moment, forget about the comparisons and everything else. Merely focus on what you want to prove:

> $|T_m - S| < \epsilon \ \forall m \geq M$.

Now, see the last line:
$$
|T_m - S| \leq |T_m - S_N| + |S_N - S| 
$$
by triangle inequality. You know that $|S_N - S| < \epsilon/2$, this part is by convergence as given in the previous slide.

The reason why the other inequality $|T_m - S_N| < \epsilon/2$ holds is the key assertion, and the confounding one. We'll unravel it piece by piece.

$T_m - S_n = (b_1 + b_2 + \ldots + b_m) - (a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n)$, by definition of the two terms.

Now, look at the choice of $m$. It has been chosen, so that $m \geq M$, where $M = \max\{f(k), 1 \leq k \leq N\}$.

What does this mean? *This means that every $a_j$ in the above subtraction gets cancelled out.* Can you see why? This is because, we know that $a_{j} = b_{f(j)}$. However, we have chosen $m$ so that $f(j) \leq m$, so $b_{f(j)}$ appears in the summation, and will cancel out with $a_j$.

Now, once the subtraction is done, what remains? *Precisely those $b_j$ remain, that are not one of the $a_j$*. That is to say, $j \neq f(k)$ for any $k=1$ to $N$.

> All in all, the quantity $|T_m - S_n|$ is the sum of *only* those $b_j$ which are **not** $a_j$ for any $j$ from $1$ to $N$. This is why we must be concerned with them, and is encapsulated in the statement $b_n : n \leq M $ and $n \neq f(k) \forall k=1,2,\ldots,N$.

Now, why is the sum of this quantity less  than $\epsilon/2$? To see this, recall that $b_j$ is a *rearrangement* of $a_j$. That is ,every $b_j$ equals $a_k$ for some $k$.

Now, we ask the following question : let's take any $b_j$ from the summation $T_m - S_N$. What do we know about the $k$ for which $b_j=a_k$? Can it be less than $N$?

> No! We've already removed all those terms when we subtracted $S_N$!

That is, $b_j=a_k$ for some $K > N+1$. So, the summation of the $b_j$s will be a summation of $a_k$s, where all the $k$s are greater than or equal to $N+1$.

But then, by the nature  of $N$,the sum of the absolute values  of these $b_j$s is going to be less than $\epsilon/2$, since that is the way we chose $N$ (last line of previous slide).

Hence, $|T_m - S_N| < \epsilon/2$, and the rest of the proof is a cakewalk.

Please ask if there are further doubts. I think a very big chunk of the proof was skipped, so it was good you got it clarified.

---

EDIT: A more formal proof of the blue box:

Let $m \geq M$. We have to prove that $|T_m - S| < \epsilon$.

Let $S = \{ n | 1 \leq n \leq m , n \neq f(k) \forall 1 \leq k \leq N\}$. Note that $|T_m- S_N| = \sum_{d \in S} b_d$. Let $K = \max\{ f^{-1}(d) : k \in S\}$. That is ,$K$ is the largest number $k$ so that $a_k = b_d$ for some $d \in S$.

Note that $\sum_{d \in S} |b_d| \leq \sum_{i=N+1}^K |a_i|$, by definition of $K$, since the terms $b_d$ will be contained in the terms $a_i$.

Now, by definition of $N$, $\sum_{i=N+1}^K a_i < \frac \epsilon 2$, so that $|T_m- S_N|  =\sum_{d \in S} b_d  < \epsilon/2$.

Finally,

$$
|T_m - S| \leq |T_m - S_N| + |S_N-S| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 < \epsilon
$$

completing the proof.

Comment: the terms $b_{n}$ with $n\leq M$ & $n\neq \{f(k): 1\leq k \leq N\}$

I still feel we are not only considering these terms.

We are trying to prove $\forall m\geq M$ which includes $m=M+1 , M+2, M+3, ... , M+100000000, ...$

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $m=M+1, M+2,\ldots M+1034482758620689655172413793, \ldots$, because the number $N$ is *fixed*, so  anyway all terms $a_j$ from $j=1, ..., N$ get cancelled out within $b_1 ,...,b_M$ itself. The rest of the $1,2,..., 1034482759620689655172413793$ terms that come after $M$, don't belong to $a_j$ from $j=1,...,N$ because those are already cancelled out by the first $M$ terms. These will come under the summation of $a_j$ *after* N, which is covered by the last line on the bottom slide.

Comment: Yes, any sum of absolute value of finite number of terms $b_{n}$ with $n \geq M$ and $f(n) \neq 1,2,3,...N$ can be made smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ as chosen. 

So then, why does the slide even mention the line:  "the terms $b_{n}$ with $n\leq M$ & $n\neq \{f(k): 1\leq k \leq N\}$ "

Does it not destroy the proof since they are irrelevant to the proof?

Comment: The sum $|T_m - S_n|$ *also includes* those terms $b_n$ for which $n \leq M$ and $n \neq f(k), 1 \leq k \leq N$, along with the remaining $1,2, ... 1000$ terms that come after $M$. You are saying : "the sum of absolute values of $b_n$ with $n \geq M$ and $f(n) \neq 1, 2, 3, ..., N$ can be made small". What about the terms $n \leq M$, which are also part of the summation? What do you do about these terms? They are relevant, that line is important because it's terms come in the summation $|T_m - S_N|$ so they have to be considered.

Comment: Yes my bad, i actually meant they are included as well in my mind, but typed it wrongly here.

Can you kindly help me out by writing a formal proof for only the part in the blue box?

Comment: I shall do so, promptly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56039/discussion-between-little-rookie-and----).

Comment: Still, looking at the slides, the proof only mention terms up till $b_{n}$ with $n\leq M$. and from there it concludes the sum of absolute value of the terms smaller than $\epsilon /2$ (forgetting about the terms with index $M+1, M+2 , ... , (any) m$

Comment: Ah, that's a mistake. Now you can see the edited proof, which will clarify some doubts, if not all. Again, please ask if any doubts, I'm here (though I may disappear in half an hour for lunch).